Power BI calculate tiered commission, commission threshold changes over time
I have sales records, if the sales involves Party B, Party A has to split revenue with Party B for all sales >$10000. This split is set by the threshold below, and the boss is free to update the threshold anytime. For example, below shows a threshold change effective on 1 Jan 2025.



Effective date
revenue threshold
Party A Split%
Party B Split%




1-1-2024
10000
50%
50%


1-1-2024
20000
80%
20%


1-1-2025
10000
50%
50%


1-1-2025
20000
70%
30%


1-1-2025
30000
90%
10%



How to get below resulting calculated columns "Party A Split $" and "Party B Split $" in Power BI?



Sales_date
Invoice#
Party-B-involved?
revenue
Party A Split $
Party B Split $




6-6-2024
001
Y
800
800 (No split, no threshold met)
0


6-6-2024
002
Y
10000
5000 (50%)
5000 (50%)


6-6-2024
003
Y
40000
32000 (80%)
8000 (20%)


7-7-2025
004
Y
800
800 (No split, no threshold met)
0


7-7-2025
005
Y
10000
5000 (50%)
5000 (50%)


7-7-2025
006
Y
40000
36000 (90%)
4000 (10%)




you can try this
Column=
VAR _date =
    MAXX (
        FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[Effective date] <= 'Table (2)'[Sales_date] ),
        'Table'[Effective date]
    )
VAR _rt =
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            'Table',
            'Table'[Effective date] = _date
                && 'Table'[revenue threshold] <= 'Table (2)'[revenue]
        ),
        'Table'[revenue threshold]
    )
VAR _split =
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            'Table',
            'Table'[Effective date] = _date
                && 'Table'[revenue threshold] = _rt
        ),
        'Table'[Party A Split%]
    )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( _rt ), 'Table (2)'[revenue], 'Table (2)'[revenue] * _split )

Column2=
VAR _date =
    MAXX (
        FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[Effective date] <= 'Table (2)'[Sales_date] ),
        'Table'[Effective date]
    )
VAR _rt =
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            'Table',
            'Table'[Effective date] = _date
                && 'Table'[revenue threshold] <= 'Table (2)'[revenue]
        ),
        'Table'[revenue threshold]
    )
VAR _split =
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            'Table',
            'Table'[Effective date] = _date
                && 'Table'[revenue threshold] = _rt
        ),
        'Table'[Party B Split%]
    )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( _rt ), 0, 'Table (2)'[revenue] * _split )



this is amazingg thank you
